# When did Captain Marvel first meet Hazmat?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-development

At the start of the *Captain Marvel* Vol. 10 comic series (2019), Captain Marvel (Carol Danvers) is introduced to Hazmat (Jennifer Takeda) by Tony Stark, who requests Carol's help in mentoring the younger hero. Carol's internal monologue says,

> I recognize her. *Hazmat*. One of the Avengers Academy kids. The kids who the Avengers were worried had the potential to become villains. No wonder Tony has taken an interest.

[image: Captain Marvel meets Hazmat in Captain Marvel Vol. 10 #1]

The two quickly become friends, and Hazmat appears regularly throughout the series as an ally.

Is this the first time they meet, or is there some prior event -- i.e., how is it that Carol can "recognize" her? Perhaps they met in some earlier issue of *Avengers Academy*, *Arena*, or *Undercover*?

Comment: You can recognize someone without having met them.  Speculating wildly, there are any number of reasons why Danvers might be familiar with Hazmat, without ever meeting her.  Perhaps there was a briefing on the Avengers Academy that Danvers attended, or even just a dossier Danvers perused.  Since they're considered to be "at risk" for villainy, perhaps all of the good guys were given a quick rundown of them in case they "got loose" and lived down to their potential...in the same way that a Wanted poster is used to help people recognize wanted criminals...